# Response.Write causing strange changes in appearance

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 examples of `Response.Write` in my project. Both work fine in Firefox but in IE, the pages width changes.

Example 1:

```
Response.Write(String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank')</script>", ResolveUrl(urlSearch)));
```

Example 2:

```
const string strResponse = "window.open('NewOrderAdd.aspx?RequestType=Modify','_blank')";
Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write(strResponse);
Response.Write("</script>");
```

Comment: The `type` attribute is not optional in HTML4, so if your doctype is not HTML5 I would first try adding `type="type="text/javascript"` to the tag (this is just speculation of course). Also, make sure it's not added in a funny place (e.g. after the closing `</body>` tag or something). The online [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) service might help you identify these non-conformities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely doing this causes the page to not conform to HTML specifications, and thus causing IE to switch to a different page rendering model (older IE/quirks). Make sure the code is actually emitted somewhere it's allowed instead - just use `RegisterStartupScript` or a `Literal` control instead of `Response.Write`.